# Are JDBC connections supposed to match the netstat network connections?

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, tomcat, jdbc, transactions

We have a Tomcat6/Hibernate 3.x/Postgres application, and I'm <s>helplessly out of my depth</s> a little unclear on what constitutes a "connection" between the app server and the DB, at least as far as JDBC goes.

Ostensibly we're using a connection pool ([Tomcat JDBC](http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/tomcat/jdbc-pool.html)) that opens 10 connections at startup. Netstat seems to confirm this:

```
netstat -nato | grep 5432
::ffff:192.168.42.11:5432   ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
::ffff:192.168.42.11:5432   ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
::ffff:192.168.42.11:5432   ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
::ffff:192.168.42.11:5432   ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
::ffff:192.168.42.11:5432   ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
::ffff:192.168.42.11:5432   ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
::ffff:192.168.42.11:5432   ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
::ffff:192.168.42.11:5432   ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
::ffff:192.168.42.11:5432   ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
::ffff:192.168.42.11:5432   ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
```

But those connections always remain in the 'off' state. When I set the Hibernate logs to DEBUG for JDBC, I see a ton of `openConnection()` and `closeConnection()` calls (more than 100 for a simple web page), but the output of netstat remains unchanged.

So are JDBC and network connections not created in a 1:1 ratio? Is this just evidence of connection pooling actually working?

Comment: Yes it is evidence of the pool working.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, EJP. Little confused, though: running jconsole remotely shows me the pool cleaner, but no other threads related to the pool. Safe to assume this is just a config thing with our app and jconsole?

Comment: Why would there be any other threads related to the pool?

Comment: To be honest, I wasn't sure what I should see in the output. I guess I expected to see a separate thread for each connection in the pool (not that I have any reason to; I'm learning this as I go). Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how [connection pooling](http://vladmihalcea.com/the-anatomy-of-connection-pooling/) works. The pool opens N number of physical database connections and when the application acquires a connection, it will get a [JDBC Connection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html) proxy, and not an actual Driver Connection object.

When the application transaction is done, the [Connection.close()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close%28%29) method is called. The proxy will intercept the `close` method and simply return the Connection object to the pool, instead of actually closing the physical connection.

The reason you see so many `openConnection()` and `closeConnection()` methods can be explained as follows:

- you are using JTA, which demands [aggressive connection release](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch13.html#transactions-connection-release) on a per statement basis.
- you don't wrap your operations in a single @Transactional service methods, and Hibernate defaults to auto-commit, so every statement will run in its own specific transaction (and every statement will actually require a Connection acquire/release cycle).
- you make heavy use of Ajax, so loading the front-page is not just one HTTP request. The more asynchronous requests you made, the more transactions will be required, the more pressure you are going to put on your connection pool.

For monitoring and tuning you connection pool, I recommend you start using [FlexyPool](http://vladmihalcea.com/flexy-pool-reactive-connection-pooling/).

Comment: Ahh. We _are_ using autocommit in our Hibernate transactions, and we have set release mode to 'auto' (we're not using JTA). I will check out FlexyPool. Thanks! As soon as I have enough rep, I'm upvoting this answer -- great explanation of the relationship between JDBC and physical connections.

Comment: Thanks for your kind words. If you have any other interesting question (as this one) related to Hibernate/transactions/JDBC/Spring/Database, you can ping me and I'll take a look. FlexyPool is a small, yet powerful utility, that's being in use by some major players in our industry (banks from US and Swiss).